# I have 4 oracle SQL queries which I want to have in one result

Tags: sql, oracle

These 4 queries produce the desired result, however I want to wrap these queries into ONE query which return each query as a horizontal column with the corresponding queries result vertically.

I have limited all the queries to rownum <= 20.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT count(tl.usr) as "Antall oppslag" FROM TABLE tl WHERE 
tl.timestamp >= (sysdate - (1/24)) GROUP BY tl.usr ORDER BY count(tl.usr) desc) WHERE 
rownum <= 20;

SELECT * FROM (SELECT count(tl.usr) as "Antall oppslag" FROM TABLE tl WHERE 
tl.timestamp >= (sysdate - (1)) GROUP BY tl.usr ORDER BY count(tl.usr) desc) WHERE 
rownum <= 20;

SELECT * FROM (SELECT count(tl.usr) as "Antall oppslag" FROM TABLE tl WHERE 
tl.timestamp >= (sysdate - (7)) GROUP BY tl.usr ORDER BY count(tl.usr) desc) WHERE 
rownum <= 20;

SELECT * FROM (SELECT count(tl.usr) as "Antall oppslag" FROM TABLE tl WHERE 
tl.timestamp >= (sysdate - (30)) GROUP BY tl.usr ORDER BY count(tl.usr) desc) WHERE 
rownum <= 20;
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

EDIT: I would like to specify that I do not want the results on top of each other. The different queries has to be horizontal columns while their respective results go vertically.a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join them by their rownum (remember to alias rownum)

```
select * from 
(
SELECT rownum rownr, a.* FROM (SELECT count(tl.usr) as "Antall oppslag" FROM TABLE tl WHERE 
tl.timestamp >= (sysdate - (1/24)) GROUP BY tl.usr ORDER BY count(tl.usr) desc) a WHERE 
rownum <= 20
) a,
(
SELECT rownum rownr, b.* FROM (SELECT count(tl.usr) as "Antall oppslag" FROM TABLE tl WHERE 
tl.timestamp >= (sysdate - (1)) GROUP BY tl.usr ORDER BY count(tl.usr) desc) b WHERE 
rownum <= 20
) b, 
(
SELECT rownum rownr, c.* FROM (SELECT count(tl.usr) as "Antall oppslag" FROM TABLE tl WHERE 
tl.timestamp >= (sysdate - (7)) GROUP BY tl.usr ORDER BY count(tl.usr) desc) c WHERE 
rownum <= 20
) c,
(
SELECT  rownum rownr, d.* FROM (SELECT count(tl.usr) as "Antall oppslag" FROM TABLE tl WHERE 
tl.timestamp >= (sysdate - (30)) GROUP BY tl.usr ORDER BY count(tl.usr) desc) d WHERE 
rownum <= 20
) d
where a.rownr = b.rownr 
and a.rownr = c.rownr
and a.rownr = d.rownr
```

Comment: Ahh this looks perfect. Let me try it out before I accept the answer. Very nice. I actually made a very similar query before, but I forgot the a.rownum = b.rownum and so on, so I got a very bad result.

Comment: actually the table references is inside the subqueries. Is it reference able from outside the subqueries? I am getting error that the tables a, b, c, d does not exist. More specifically it sais "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification" on the line where I say a.rownum = b.rownum

Comment: @Karrax:i think you should use alias for rownum for eg:`SELECT rownum rwnum` ....... where a.rwnum=b.rwnum

Comment: @JensSchauder , sorry but it seems that the a.* does not work. I cannot retrieve data from the sub query for some reason. I keep getting error message that "a" is invalid identifier

Comment: If I move the rownum inside the subquery and just use select * outside I get that rownum is not a valid group by clause (sadly)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are executing. Maybe you need to give unique aliases to the rownum columns? I have a simplified working version here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1c06/4 If you provide create scripts for (simplified versions of) your tables we can make a complete solution.

Comment: @JensSchauder: What if the `inline view A `returns less number of rows ? `For example`: If `A returns 10 records` ,`B 20` ,`c 20 `,`d 20`.The at the end we have four columns for `A  B  C  D` with all containing `10 rows` .Here you are assuming that all returns more than 20 rows

Comment: @GauravSoni you are right. if you want the maximum number of rows just use outer joins instead of inner joins.

Comment: @JensSchauder:No we can't just use outerjoin in this because we don't know which inline view is returning max number of rows ,we need to use outer join based on that only otherwise we lost data .

Comment: you should be ablt to do it with a full outer join http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Full_outer_join (and a somewhat convoluted join condition) or with an additional "table" for the number 1 to 20: select * from (select level x from dual connect by  level <=20)

Comment: @JensSchauder:I don't know how to implement this with full outerjoin on multiple tables.`SELECT A.*, B.*, C.*
FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN B ON B.x = A.x 
FULL OUTER JOIN C ON C.x = A.x OR C.x = B.x` does this works?  otherwise we can easily implement this with additional table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9272/discussion-between-gaurav-soni-and-jens-schauder)